# sitemap.xml works on development but 404 errors on production

Tags: python, django, django-sitemaps

I've been following the documentation to add a sitemap to my website, everything works perfectly on development, once I upload to production, I have 404 errors as in sitemap can't be found. I checked the database on production to make sure the SITE_ID is the same as the pk of the site registered in database.

This is my installed app in settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for icerd project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

from django.conf import global_settings
# Add custom languages not provided by Django
from django.conf import locale
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from icerd.productions import production_debug, production_secret_key, allowed_host, production_caches_location

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = production_debug

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = production_secret_key

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"] if DEBUG else allowed_host
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "registration.User"

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig',
    'administration.apps.AdministrationConfig',
    'registration.apps.RegistrationConfig',
]

# Multisite settings
SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',

    # DataFlair #Caching Middleware
    # 'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'registration.middleware.ActiveUserMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'icerd.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'icerd.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        BASE_DIR / "static",
    ]

if not DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Message storage
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'

# Number of seconds of inactivity before a user is marked offline
USER_ONLINE_TIMEOUT = 300

# Number of seconds that we will keep track of inactive users for before
# their last seen is removed from the cache
USER_LASTSEEN_TIMEOUT = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

# Caches settings
CACHES_LOCATION = production_caches_location

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': CACHES_LOCATION,
    }
}

# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*********'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = ""
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = True

ADMINS = [
    ('Admin', 'example@gmail.com'),
]

MANAGERS = [
    ('Admin', 'example@gmail.com'),
]

# Language translation settings

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'cr-ht': {
        'bidi': False,  # right-to-left
        'code': 'cr-ht',
        'name': 'Haitian Creole',
        'name_local': "Kreyòl",
    },
}

LANG_INFO = dict(locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO

LANGUAGES = (
    ('cr-ht', _('Kreyòl')),
    ('fr', _('Français')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)

# Languages using BiDi (right-to-left) layout
LANGUAGES_BIDI = global_settings.LANGUAGES_BIDI + ["cr-ht"]

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'locale'),
)

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Extra deployment parameters
if not DEBUG:
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

    SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
    SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True

    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 900  # 15 minutes

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_URL

# The number of seconds a password reset link is valid for (in second)
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 3600  # 1 hour
```

and this is my urls.py (root project where settings.py file is)

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.urls import path, include

from icerd import settings
from icerd.sitemaps import StaticViewSitemap

admin.site.site_header = "ICERD' website Administration"
admin.site.site_title = 'Administration'
admin.site.index_title = 'ICERD'

sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
         name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),
    path('registration/', include('registration.urls')),
    path('administration/', include('administration.urls')),
    path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="password/reset_password.html"),
         name='reset_password'),
    path('reset_password_sent/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="password/reset_password_sent.html"),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="password/reset_password_form.html"),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset_password_complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="password/reset_password_done.html"),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL,
        document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    )
```

and this is my sitemaps.py (also in root, where settings.py is)

```
# sitemaps.py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse


class StaticViewSitemap(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'weekly'

    def items(self):
        return [
            'homepage:homepage',
            'homepage:get_logo',
            'homepage:about_us',
            'homepage:login',
            'homepage:logout',
        ]

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

After all those, I made sure to run migrations, go to django admin and replace 'example.com'  in sites' table.

If I run the same code on my computer, everything works fine, production doesn't work.
I use a debian vps to host my website using nginx and gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your nginx server block

`rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`

If it helps this means your browser is trying to access "/sitemap.xml/" (not "/sitemap.xml")